# PDO Insert on Update if id exist MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my sql with an submit form and also insert if the submit data doesn't exist.

My SQL database is like this

```
-------------------------------
| id | plan   | price | percent |
| 1  | Plan 1 |   1   |   115   |
| 2  | Plan 2 |   2   |   117   |
-------------------------------
```

My submit form will gives this array after submiting.

```
Array
(
    [plan] => Array
        (
            [0] => Plan 1
            [1] => Plan 2
            [2] => Plan 3
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.00000000
            [1] => 2.00000000
            [2] => 5.00000000
        )

    [percent] => Array
        (
            [0] => 115.0000
            [1] => 117.0000
            [2] => 120.0000
        )

)
```

I want to update mysql database if the ID is same for the data that I submit.

After submiting the form, the array is like this

```
Array
(
    [plan] => Array
        (
            [0] => Plan 1
            [1] => Plan 2
            [2] => Plan 3
        )

    [price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.00000000
            [1] => 20.00000000
            [2] => 5.00000000
        )

    [percent] => Array
        (
            [0] => 120.0000
            [1] => 125.0000
            [2] => 130.0000
        )

)
```

I've made this PDO

```
$totalData = sizeof($data['plan']);
for($i=0;$i<$totalData;$i++) {
    print_r($data['price'][$i]);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO plans_sub 
                    (plan, price, percent, main_id) 
             VALUES (:plan, :price, :percent, :main_id) 
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                plan = :planOne, 
                price = :priceOne, 
                percent = :percentOne, 
                main_id = :main_idOne");
      $stmt->bindValue(':plan', isset($data['plan'][$i]) ? $data['plan'][$i] : NULL);
      $stmt->bindValue(':price', isset($data['price'][$i]) ? $data['price'][$i] : NULL);
      $stmt->bindValue(':percent', isset($data['percent'][$i]) ? $data['percent'][$i] : NULL);
      $stmt->bindValue(':main_id', $_POST['id']);
      $stmt->bindValue(':planOne', isset($data['plan'][$i]) ? $data['plan'][$i] : NULL);
      $stmt->bindValue(':priceOne', isset($data['price'][$i]) ? $data['price'][$i] : NULL);
      $stmt->bindValue(':percentOne', isset($data['percent'][$i]) ? $data['percent'][$i] : NULL);
      $stmt->bindValue(':main_idOne', $_POST['id']);
      $stmt->execute();
}
```

After submiting the form, the code always give me new data in mysql database and not updating the same data before.

```
-------------------------------
| id | plan   | price | percent |
| 1  | Plan 1 |   1   |   115   |
| 2  | Plan 2 |   2   |   117   |
| 3  | Plan 1 |   1   |   115   |
| 4  | Plan 2 |   2   |   117   |
| 5  | Plan 1 |   1   |   115   |
| 6  | Plan 2 |   2   |   117   |
-------------------------------
```

What I want is to update the data if exist and add new data if they are not in the database.

what I want is update the data if exist and add new if not exist

```
-------------------------------
| id | plan   | price | percent |
| 1  | Plan 1 |   10   |   120   |
| 2  | Plan 2 |   20   |   125   |
| 3  | Plan 3 |   50   |   130   |
-------------------------------
```

please help me

==============================EDIT=============================

```
CREATE TABLE `plans_sub` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `plan` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(20,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `percent` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `main_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `plans_sub` (`id`, `plan`, `price`, `percent`, `main_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Plan 1', '1.00000000', '50.0000', 1),
(2, 'Plan 1', '1.00000000', '115.0000', 2),
(3, 'Plan 2', '2.00000000', '117.0000', 2),

ALTER TABLE `plans_sub`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: Where is `main_id` in the table??

Comment: Yes I set these 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: Please see my updated first post, I want to update the data if exist and add new if not exist

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Which field is defined as unique in the schema. _Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE plans_sub;` and copy/paste the output to your question_

Comment: please see updated first post, main_id is the ID of table plans, and the plans_sub is the child of it

Comment: So none of the columns are defined as unique, So how will it fail an insert and be pushed into the ON DUPICATE code??

Comment: can you help me? just want figure this out "What I want is to update the data if exist and add new data if they are not in the exist."

Comment: Just define main_id (or whatever) as unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to fix this.

Just add **ID** in prepared statements and the code will work

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO plans_sub 
                    (id, plan, price, percent, main_id) 
             VALUES (:id, :plan, :price, :percent, :main_id) 
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                plan = :planOne, 
                price = :priceOne, 
                percent = :percentOne, 
                main_id = :main_idOne");
```

Hope this can help everyone better!